# Scala simplify nested monads

Tags: scala, monads, monad-transformers

I have some code written in Lift. Basically its nested Box (similar monad to Option). I'd like to simplify it a little bit if possible. Preferably add type parameter so this could be easily changed to string or double if needed. Here is the code

```
tryo(r.param("boolean parameter").map(_.toBoolean)).map(_.openOr(false)).openOr(false)
```

"tryo" is helper function to catch and wrap results in Box if exception occurs and r is Req object. "param" function returns Box[String] (that comes from request param). 
I'd like to make it working for Int's String's etc. and if possible get rid of nested map/openOr (getOrElse in you think in Option types).

Monad transformers ?

Answer (score 6):

`flatMap` that sh*t!

```
r.param("boolean parameter").flatMap(tryo(_.toBoolean)).openOr(false)
```

Or, use a for comprehension:

```
val result = for {
  param <- r.param("boolean parameter")
  bool <- tryo(param.toBoolean)
} yield bool
result openOr false
```

But that doesn't solve your ability to get different types. For that I would suggest something like:

```
def asOrDefault[T](input: Box[Any])(default: => T): T = input.flatMap(tryo(_.asInstanceOf[T])).openOr(default)

asOrDefault(r.param("any param"))(0)
```

This is untested... Note also that `scala.util.control.Exception.allCatch.opt()` will return an `Option` just like `tryo` returns a `Box`.

Comment: `"2".asInstanceOf[Int]`? – No.

Comment: For comprehension is more elaborate than my code -1 for that but I like other approaches. Thanks !

Comment: Lukasz, perhaps, though I'd argue the for comprehension is clearer than your example. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to absract the type, you need to abstract both the default value, and the conversion from a string:

```
case class Converter[T]( default: T, fromString: String => T )
```

Then define implicit instances for your types:

```
implicit val intConverter = Converter[Int]( 0, _.toInt )
implicit val boolConverter = Converter[Boolean]( false, _.toBoolean )
```

Finally, use pr1001 answer, using an implicitly provided value of converter:

```
def asOrDefault[T](input: Box[String])(implicit conv: Converter[T]): T = input.flatMap(
  s => tryo( conv.fromString(s))).openOr(conv.default)
```

The compiler will select the appropriate converter instance for you:

```
asOrDefault[Int]( input.param("some int param") )
asOrDefault[Boolean]( input.param("some boolean param") )
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine.

Comment: I hoped for monad transforms :P

Answer (score 0):

My little bit tweaked version building on @pr1001 and @paradigmatic ground.

```
case class Converter[T]( fromString: String => T )

implicit val boolConverter = Converter(_.toBoolean) 

implicit val intConverter = Converter(_.toInt)

def asOrDefault[T](input: Box[String], default: T)(implicit conv: Converter[T]): T =       
  input.flatMap( s => tryo(conv.fromString(s))).openOr(default)
```

And usage in my case:

```
def prettyPrint(implicit r: Req) = asOrDefault(r.param("prettyPrint"), false)

def maxResults(implicit r: Req): Int = asOrDefault(r.param("maxResults"), 20)
```